# Remainder of $2^{125}/13$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Remainder of $2^{125}/13$

According to Microsoft Excel, the answer is 6

[image]

I was expecting a shorter pattern with remainders such as 3,6,12,...

How to go about doing this simply?

I thought of something like

$$2^{125} = (26-24)^{125}$$

$$2^{125} = (28-26)^{125}$$

Those don't seem to help.

Comment: Are you familiar with congruences, i.e. modular arithmetic?

Comment: You _have_ a short pattern with remainders such as $3, 6, 12$. The pattern repeats after every $12$ steps. How much shorter did you need the pattern to be?

Answer (score 7):

This problem can be solved with modular arithmetic.

By Fermat's little theorem $2^{12}\equiv 1 \bmod 13$

Therefore $2^{125}=(2^{12})^{10}\times 2^5\equiv 1\times 32\equiv 6  \bmod 13$

Answer (score 1):

In a little different way than the given answer, there is this rule for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $a\in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$ and $b\in \mathbb{Z}_n$:
  $$ a^b\bmod n \equiv a^{b\bmod \varphi(n)}\mod n, $$
where $\varphi$ indicates [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). Here we have that $2$ and $13$ are coprime, thus $2\in  \mathbb{Z}_{13}^*$ (since $13$ is a prime, every element of $\mathbb{Z}_{13} \setminus \{0\}$ is invertible) and this gives
  $$ 2^{125 \bmod 12} \equiv 2^5 \equiv 6 \mod 13. $$

Comment: [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) requires that $\,a\,$ is coprime to $\,n\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for the hint, I've made an edit on that.

Comment: You are using $\bmod$ in two different ways: (1) $a\bmod b$ is the remainder when $a$ is divided by $b$, and (2) $p\equiv q\mod m$ means $p$ and $q$ both leave the same remainder on division by $m$.  For the first usage, I changed \mod to \bmod so instead of $125\mod12$ you see $125\bmod 12$.  "b" means "binary" so the spacing conventions are those of binary operation symbols such as $\text{“}{+}\text{''}$. For the second usage,$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$the form $$ a\equiv b\equiv c\equiv d\equiv \cdots \mod m, $$ with $\bmod m$ appearing only once, should be used, where $\bmod m$ applies to the entire line. The congruence $a\equiv b\mod m$ is parsed as $(a\equiv b)\mod m$, and does not refer to anything called $a\bmod m$ or $b\bmod m$.  I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Your point would be much clearer if you used proper notation, i.e. $\ p\equiv q\pmod m,\,$ not $\ p\equiv q\mod n.\, $ The latter greatly enhances such confusion.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you for clarifying the use of notation!

Comment: @BillDubuque Indeed, many times I've been confronted with this notation without any explanation (e.g. courses where modular arithmetic is introduced). But Michael Hardy's comments were still helpful.

Comment: @BillDubuque : I think $(p\equiv q) \mod m$ would be clearer than either of those, since it makes it clear that it doesn't refer to a binary operation that might be denoted $q\bmod m$.  I.e. it's NOT $p\equiv (q\bmod m)$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to look for a power of $2$ that is close to a multiple of 13. Starting with $2$, $4$, $8$, etc. you find that $64 = 2^8$ is exactly one less than $65 = 5\times 13$. In mod notation, $$2^6 \equiv -1 \bmod 13.$$

Now exponentiate both sides to get the largest exponent you can below $125$:
$$(2^6)^{20} \equiv (-1)^{20} \bmod 13$$
so that $$2^{120} \equiv 1 \bmod 13.$$ Finally multiply both sides by $2^5$ to get $$2^{125} \equiv 32 \bmod 13$$ and work out by hand that the remainder you get when you divide $32$ by $13$ is $6$.